# How to hide row based on cell value in last column of worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro where the last column of a worksheet is searched for a value, and if that value is found in a cell that cell's entire row is hidden. I'm also trying to use a dynamic range for this as the last column will change.

```
With ws1

LastColumn = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, LastColumn).End(xlUp).Row

Set rDataRange = .Range(.Cells(2, LastColumn), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

For Each rCell in RDataRange 
    If rCell.Value = "Yes" Then
        rCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next rCell
End With
```

Anyone have an idea as to why this might not be working?

Comment: You will have to fully qualify the `With` statement related parts. e.g. `Set rDataRange = Range(Cells(2, LastColumn), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
` should be `Set rDataRange = .Range(.Cells(2, LastColumn), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
`

Comment: Ah that's my bad, the computer I'm working on doesn't have internet access so I had to manually retype on my phone. It did read `Set rDataRange = .Range(.Cells(2, LastColumn), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))` in my code, just mistyped it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastColumn As Long, Lastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim str As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        str = "Test"
        LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, LastColumn).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To Lastrow

            If .Cells(i, LastColumn).Value = str Then
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: should be `.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True`

Comment: Thanks! That is definitely a better way to loop through the rows.

Comment: This is a good solution, but on a sidenote; I see people implement this loop often while the `.FindNext` function will work faster and should improve calculationtime significantly on large databases (who want's to loop 100.000 rows when you can jump straight to a found value?) :)